# updating with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following code:

```
class RatingsData {

    var ratings = [NSManagedObject]()

    func fetchFromDatabase() -> Void {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Rating")
        var error: NSError?

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]?

        if let results = fetchedResults {
            ratings = results
        } else {
            println("error fetching from database")
        }

    }

    func addTitle(newTitle:String) -> Void {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Rating", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        let title = Rating(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        //new way
        title.title = newTitle
        println("New rating title \(newTitle) saved")

        var error: NSError?
        if !managedContext.save(&error) {
            println("could not save")
        }

    }

    func addStar(title: String, star: NSData) -> Void {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Rating", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        let request = NSFetchRequest()
        request.entity = entityDescription

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title  = %@", title)
        request.predicate = predicate

        var error: NSError?
        var results = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]?

        results?[0].setValue(star, forKey: "star")
        println("new rating star saved")

        if !managedContext.save(&error) {
            println("could not save")
        }

    }
}
```

Rating is the entity, title and star the attribute.
It works fine, but when I tap onto the same title to change the rating, the app crashes. When tapping on the same title, I would like to be able to update the star image and display it in the table view.

I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Can you please put the crash log here?

Comment: I managed to make the code work changing it, I still don't understand why the one above crashes. The star image is nil when I try to return the same object for the second time.